# how to query in python to get the NULL value documents from mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I have written a query to get all the documents where the question is null in mongodb.

```
db.warehouse.find({"question":null})
```

This part of the code is working fine if I query it on mongodb Prompt.
However, If get it to python, It say undefined reference null.
How do I solve this problem, If I assign it to a variable then this null becomes a string. How do I pass null from python

Comment: Try entering {"question":null} in your interpreter. Python probably won't like it, so it won't like it as an argument to a function either.

Answer (score 2):

python does not have a null keyword,

try:

```
db.warehouse.find({"question":None})
```

also while we dont mind answering these questions a google search for "reference error null python" would lead directly to a soluton